# How to redirect non-logged in users to wordpress login page and bypass some page IDs?

Tags: redirect

How to redirect all non-logged in users to the default wordpress login page and bypass some pages using it's slug ID?

Comment: You can redirect users to login page with `wp_safe_redirect( wp_login_url() );` function. but I don't understand your question exactly.

Comment: What I wish to achieve is to block the full WP and redirect to wp-login but bypass some pages which even a non-loggedin user can view. I hope I'm more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
add_action('wp', 'custom_user_redirect');
function custom_user_redirect() {
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {return;}
    // array of page IDs OR slugs to allow access to
    $skippages = array(11, 23, 12); 
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        if (is_page($page)) {return;}
    }
    wp_safe_redirect(wp_login_url());
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're adding to `wp` (which is the first time I've read this hook) instead of `init` or `template_redirect`?

Comment: not really I was just in a rush and didn't think about the hook too much, either of those would work too